# Why the table row is not getting deleted by using following code in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, rowdeleting

I've following HTML of a table. The actual table is too large. For your reference I've shown only two rows from this large HTML table:

```
<table   id="blacklistgrid"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr  id="Row1">
      <th style="vertical-align:middle" >Pack Of</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="apnd-test">
    <tr id="reb1">
      <td><input type="text" name="pack[1]" id="pack_1" value="100" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity[1]" id="quantity_1" value="10" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="volume[1]" id="volume_1" value="1000" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <select id="units_1" name="units[1]" class="form-control">
            <option value="" >Select Unit</option>
            <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>
            <option value="7" >oz</option>
            <option value="9" >ml</option>
            <option value="10" >L</option>
            <option value="12"  selected="selected">gms</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="amount[1]" id="amount_1" value="3.00" class="form-control" size="9"/><button class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" onclick="delete_rebate(this.id);return false;" type="button" style="margin: -26px -14px;float: right; color:#C00; opacity: 2;">×</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="reb2">
      <td><input type="text" name="pack[2]" id="pack_2" value="200" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity[2]" id="quantity_2" value="20" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="volume[2]" id="volume_2" value="2000" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <select id="units_2" name="units[2]" class="form-control">
            <option value="" >Select Unit</option>
            <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>
            <option value="7" >oz</option>
            <option value="9" >ml</option>
            <option value="10"  selected="selected">L</option>
            <option value="12" >gms</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="amount[2]" id="amount_2" value="6.00" class="form-control" size="9"/><button class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" onclick="delete_rebate(this.id);return false;" type="button" style="margin: -26px -14px;float: right; color:#C00; opacity: 2;">×</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The jQuery function I wrote is as follows:

```
function delete_rebate(field) {
  $('#'+field).remove();    
}
```

But it's not working. Can anyone please help me in this regard? If you want any more information regarding the issue I can provide you the same.

Comment: add an alert(field); to that function .. so you can see what the value of field is. you may not be passing the correct id to the delete_rebate function

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the call to the function.

I think you may have made a common problem with the id.

Do a console log to see what the value of field is inside your delete rebate.

keep in mind that writing a function that does only 1 short task like this will slow down and clutter your code.

Just use `ELEMENT.remove();` its clean and simple.

if this is not working look into the jquery EQ function

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure to call the function delete_rebate()?
If so, you might be trying to call the function before the document is fully loaded. 
I tried this with a tr (id="reb2") and it worked:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        delete_rebate('reb2');
    });

    function delete_rebate(field) {
       $('#'+field).remove();    
    }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cAS9v/3/

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your function on the click of a button and use `this.id`. However in this context `this` refers to the button. Instead you need to look for the table row. ALso don't hard code your event handlers into the HTML, assign them:

```
$(".apnd-test button.close").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```